# CKeditor toolbar missing when edit nodes but shows when edit blocks(Dupal 7)

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

Reently when I edit any content type the CKeditor toolbar doesn't show but when I edit a bock it does. In both cases I am using the Full HTML text format. I have reinstalled CKeditor several times. I'm using CKeditor 7.x-1.17 and Drupal 7.50 although the problem occurred before I upgraded to 7.5.

Help!

Comment: Resolved the problem by changing the jquery to the default.  It was 1.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by changing the jquery version to the default. It was 1.10